# Naming conventions in a Python library

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I'm implementing a search algorithm (let's call it MyAlg) in a python package. Since the algorithm is super-duper complicated, the package has to contain an auxiliary class for algorithm options. Currently I'm developing the entire package by myself (and I'm not a programmer), however I expect 1-2 programmers to join the project later. This would be my first project that will involve external programmers. Thus, in order to make their lifes easier, how should I name this class: Options, OptionsMyAlg, MyAlgOptions or anything else?

What would you suggest me to read in this topic except for http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html ?

Thank you
Yuri 
[cross posted from here: http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.684669.0 will update the answers in both places]

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (styleguide for Python code).

Answer (score 2):

Just naming it `Options` should be fine.  The Python standard library generally takes the philosophy that namespaces make it easy and manageable for different packages to have identically named things.  For example, `open` is both a builtin and a function in the `os` module, several different modules define an `Error` exception class, and so on.

This is why it's generally considered bad form to say `from some_module import *` since it makes it unclear to which `open` your code refers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If it all fits in one file, name the class Options.  Then your users can write:

```
import myalg

searchOpts = myalg.Options()
searchOpts.whatever()

mySearcher = myalg.SearchAlg(searchOpts)
mySearcher.search("where's waldo?")
```

Note the Python Style Guide referenced in another answer suggests that packages should be named with all lowercase letters.